# Symfony post submit event doesnt modify dynamic field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Here is my case:

I have two fields in a form, the second field values depends on the value selected on the first field.

I'm doing this to modify the second field:

```
$builder->add('firstField',EntityType::class, array(class => First::class));

$formModifier = function(FormInterface $formBuilder, $data = null){
  if($data != null){
    $formBuilder->add('secondField', EntityType::class, array(
                      class => Second::class,
                      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($data) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                              ->where('s.field = :data')
                              ->setParameter('data', $data)
                            ;
                       });
  } else {
    $formBUilder->add('secondField', HiddenType::class, array('required' => false);
  }
}

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getData());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('firstField')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier){
                $data = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $data);
            }
        );
```

Ajax:

```
        var $firstField = $('#firstField');
        $(document).on('change', '#firstField', function(){
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = {};
            data['id'] = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data: data,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#secondField').html(
                        $(html).find('#secondField').html()
                    );
                }
            })
        });
```

The data is sent correctly via ajax, but i never get the correct response because it doesn't ever enter in the POST_SUBMIT event listener as i tried to debug and use some var_dump to check it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which response code do you have? 200, 400...?

Comment: I get 200 response code after selecting the first field, but the second field does not change

Comment: Ok, could you add also your javascript with the Ajax call. Do you have validation errors on your form? maybe on other fields

Comment: No, I don't have any validation errors on the other fields. I added the ajax i'm using. The ajax post submits the correct data, but the post submit event doesn't get triggered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your js ajax function `data['id'] = $(this).val();` replace $data['id'] with input/select name and try again. Check js example here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I discovered myself that what you said was the actual issue. The ajax was the problem. And I don't understand why because I did something similar to this on other part of my project and it worked.. but anyway, the correct way to pass the data to the controller is ```data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();``` as stated in the docs. 

Thanks a lot for your help @qdequippe